# Edit HTML code in AJAX call before including it to the page

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I want to highlight the link of the current page in my Navbar. The trouble is that I'm including the navbar code into each page like this:

```
            $.ajax({
            url: "includes/navbar.html",
            success: function (result) {
                $("body").prepend(result);
            }
        });
```

now, if I try to select the link that I want to highlight after this call, nothing happens, because the elements are not in the page yet. But I need to perform this operation on load so the $(document).on('event ... trick won't work.

Now, I can either copy and paste my navbar.html code into all of my pages, or I should find a way to edit the code within the function (result) before adding it to the body of the page.

If I do

```
var html = $(".nav-link", $.parseHTML(result)).addClass("highlight");
                console.log(html);
                $("body").prepend(result);
```

I see that the class is added but of course I need to "apply" the changes to the variable result or it won't show up in my page. But I can't find a way to do just that.

Any ideas? I think I'm going about this all wrong... but I can't imagine that I have to either duplicate all of that code in my page or I can't highlight the currently open page.

Comment: Did you try to use $('body').prepend(html) in your second code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I try to select the link that I want to highlight after this call, nothing happens, because the elements are not in the page yet.

The solution to this is to select the link within the `success` callback that you define within the `$.ajax` call, rather than directly after the `$.ajax` call. After you use `.prepend` in the `success` function to insert the navbar into the body, code later in that same function can select the navbar normally, as if it had always been on the page.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "includes/navbar.html",
    success: function(result) {
        $("body").prepend(result);
        $(".navbar .nav-link").addClass("highlight");
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes! Brilliant! Thank you.